# Is there a way how to truncate all tables using liquibase?

Tags: java, database, oracle, liquibase

I would like to truncate all data from an application before it goes to production I was looking into the documentation and didn't find anything about truncating tables using liquibase. so I was wondering if anybody else solved something similar

Comment: delete does not work? http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/delete.html

Comment: Liquibase is not about data but about the db structure. Hence there is no build in mechanism to delete data.

Comment: @Jens this is not really true. See the link to the documentation I posted above.

Comment: @Henry: You are right. I did not know about the delete statement. But liquibase is still about db structure and not the the data inside (even though there are a couple of data related tasks).

Comment: +1  I had this issue too.  Truncate is a much faster alternative.  I wish the limitations of it being "about structure not data" were on the feature list instead of of mentioning features like "Complex commands like Add Lookup Table and Merge Columns".

Answer (score 9):

You can use native SQL.  It isn't liquibase constructs as such, and not DB agnostic, but I suspect truncate commands should be supported by any DB platform that liquibase supports.  Of course, be careful of Foreign Key references when truncating any table, and make sure you truncate in the right order.

For example:

```
<changeSet author="eric.b" id="10288-201-5">
    <comment>Clear any existing legacy data in the tables</comment>
    <sql splitStatements="true">
        TRUNCATE TABLE ADDRESS;
        TRUNCATE TABLE PHONE;
        TRUNCATE TABLE USERS;
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```